# What's the best method to responsibly dispose of used alkaline batteries?

Tags: batteries

Years ago, I would have typically tossed typical, Alkaline batteries in the trash.  I have been reading more and more on this topic, and while I see that rechargeable batteries should be recycled, I'm finding conflicting evidence on how best to dispose of Alkaline batteries.

For example, [Duracell claims](http://www.duracell.com/en-us/battery-care-and-disposal) that since they removed the mercury from batteries, they're safe for disposal.  But [others claim](http://blog.ecycler.com/2011/03/31/alkaline-batteries/) (see Disqus comments at the bottom) that since all batteries contain various kinds of heavy heavy metals and should thus be recycled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the UK (and most, if not all, of the EU):

- some supermarkets have recycling bins for small batteries.
- Every community has a household waste recycling centre with containers for old batteries (including both lead-acid car batteries and small appliance batteries like AA batteries).

---

EU [Directive 206/66/EC](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ%3aL:2006:266:0001:0014%3aen%3aPDF) says

> In order to protect the environment, waste batteries and
>   accumulators should be collected. For portable batteries
>   and accumulators, collection schemes achieving a high
>   collection rate should be established. This means setting
>   up collection schemes so that end-users can discard all
>   waste portable batteries and accumulators conveniently
>   and free of charge

Comment: Same in Belgium

Comment: Actually EU-wide.  Batteries are a hazardous waste stream and must be separated to comply with EU directives (which are enforced by local laws).

Comment: @Marko: I've updated the answer to include the EU. I've left wriggle room as I don't know the situation in all of the EU, for example perhaps remote villages in recent accession states don't all have separate facilities for batteries?

Answer (score 1):

Even though heavy metals are not much of a concern anymore with any batteries (even the more exotic rechargeable chemistries don't contain toxic heavy metals anymore), a big concern for waste disposal and the environment is the use of strong acids in these batteries. Even a single battery can contain enough acid to throw the pH of hundreds of liters of ground water out of whack so as to kill most of the ground life. When the waste is burned instead of dumped, the acids and other electrolyte components cause relatively high amounts of harmful emissions (like sulphur dioxide) to be produced in the process - although modern plants filter this out pretty effectively.

It is generally better for the environment to collect batteries separately for these reasons, even if the economics are not necessarily that good for recouping the materials out of these batteries.

Answer (score 0):

In my community, I collect my old batteries and they're disposed of at the hazardous waste depot.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what recycling and disposal services are available to you, and at what price.

People or governments running a recycling or disposal business will tend to recommend their services, in order to make more money.  Some governments have more impartial advice.  So it is hard to find the best action to take.

No batteries are designed for eating, drinking, or growing plants from.  I'm certainly not surprised if there are elements newly found in them that are toxic, but it is a matter of the dose.  A waste stream concentrates the dose.

Mercury was present once upon a time, but it became such a problem that it was removed.  From all but mercury batteries.  ;-)

Rechargeable batteries such as NiCd ought to avoid ground disposal for reasons of the Cd, and the risk of it leaching into water table.  But ground disposal can be designed to reduce this risk.

Rechargeable batteries such as NiMH can probably be recycled for their nickel, but the economics will depend on the nickel price.

Rechargeable batteries such as lead acid ought to be recycled, as the lead fetches a good price.  The lead is also toxic at the right dose.

I've heard Lithium based batteries are interesting to some because of the Lithium.

I send lead acid batteries for recycling, and dispose of alkaline, NiCd, NiMH, and lithium in the common waste stream run by the local government, because that stream is designed for those goods.  I'm in a rural area, so my options are quite limited.